# Error: error creating Storage gateway SMB file Share: InvalidGatewayRequestExeption

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, aws-storage-gateway

I tried to run following terraform code o create test smb share but got error

see code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share" "test_smb_share" {
  authentication        = "ActiveDirectory"
  gateway_arn           = "arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:145429107744:gateway/sgw-4xxxxxxx"
  default_storage_class = "S3_STANDARD"
  location_arn          = "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxx"
  role_arn              = "arn:aws:iam::145429107744:role/service-role/StorageGatewayBucketAccessRolee896cdf0-cb46-4471-a0de-119f69f87e"
  valid_user_list       = ["@Domain Admins","@Admins"]
  kms_encrypted         = "true"
  kms_key_arn           = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:145429107744:key/8c4b962b-c00a-4a32-8fbd-76b174efb609"
  tags = {
                atomdev     =   "prod"
                atomdomain  =   "xxxxxx"
                atomos      =   "file system"
                atompid     =   "32"
                atomrole    =   "storage"
  }
}
```

aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share.test_smb_share: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating Storage Gateway SMB File Share: InvalidGatewayRequestException: OverlappingLocations
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "e8f7466d-23af-4a4c-a457-d39a0f99406d"
│   },
│   Error_: {
│     ErrorCode: "OverlappingLocations"
│   },
│   Message_: "OverlappingLocations"
│ }
│
│   with aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share.test_smb_share,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share" "test_smb_share":
│    5: resource "aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share" "test_smb_share" {
│

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run two shares on the same SGW that have overlapping S3 locations, you'll get this error.  For example:

```
\\my-s3-bucket\folder1\data
\\my-s3-bucket\folder1
```

^ those would overlap, since one would contain a subset of the other

Comment: I have 2 SGs that has some shares write back to the same S3 locastion. not same sg